# Refresh Sheet Data through a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have my macro working beautifully, however I need the loop to run 100 times and after the 2nd time I get

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
```

I've tried the following options:

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
'ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
'ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
'Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
'ActiveSheet.Calculate
```

Yet they all will loop twice, and on the 3rd time I get the above error. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub Populate_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim b As Long

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objElementA As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim objCollectionA As Object


x = 0
While x < 101

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "website" 'make sure you've logged into the page

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 3
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4

Application.CalculateFullRebuild
'ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
'ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
'Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
'ActiveSheet.Calculate

Call IE.document.getelementbyid("name").SetAttribute("value", ActiveSheet.Range("b2").Value)
Call IE.document.getelementbyid("aw_login").SetAttribute("value", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Value)

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Type = "button" And _
        objCollection(i).Value = "Prefill" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
objElement.Click

Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

Set objCollectionA = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
a = 0
While a < objCollectionA.Length
    If objCollectionA(a).Type = "submit" And _
        objCollectionA(a).Value = "OK" Then
            Set objElementA = objCollectionA(a)
    End If
    a = a + 1
Wend
objElementA.Click

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 3
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4
IE.Quit
x = x + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 3
```

I removed that bit of code and now it runs just as it should.